# Does Windows have a JSON API that can be called from C?

Tags: c, json, winapi, api

Is there a native implementation of JSON in Windows that I can call from C? If not, what about .NET or C#? Or what if any library or implementation do people use when they wish to use JSON in a Windows app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a built-in Windows JSON parser:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

It can be called from a native language using the .NET interop facilities ([COM Callable Wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)), which may be more work for you than a truly native library, as first answer suggests.

Comment: How do you use that from C?

Comment: Sorry - let me clarify ("native" being overloaded).  There is a managed .NET JSON parser that is part of the native Windows distro, which can be accessed from C using interop (CCW).

Comment: You'll see that I have reverted the question back to the form it was in 2 years ago when I answered it. If @hippietrail wants to ask a different question then that different question would be a fit for your answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see, yes a bit confusing

Comment: Anyway, +1 for you answer!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I asked exactly the same question, only the emphasis was changed because I was disappointed with the lack of "native" answers. There are lots of questions about generic JSON + Windows + C/C++ and this one has had low views and votes for a long time so it's not like I'm pulling the rug out from under people. `\-:`

Comment: @hippietrail I'm really really peeved at what you did here. Ask a new question. It's that simple. Not impressed.

Comment: I'm sorry you're upset but this was always the intention of my question and I've been waiting a long time for an answer. Stack Overflow is about helping the many people locate an answer, the stuff about reputation and accepted answers is of minor import if all my reading of the blogs and listening to the podcasts is anything to go by.

Comment: All you had to do was ask a new question. By editing the question to ask something different, you made my answer look stupid. It's two years old. Just ask a new question.

Comment: Well again I'm sorry but the question was always about a native Windows solution preferably which was never addressed by your curt one-liner which addressed only my backup "failing that" clause. I accepted it at the time because there was no better answer. Now there's a better answer that fits the wording of the question old, new, or reverted.

Comment: The problem was that you appear to have asked the wrong question. You meant to ask one question, but asked a different question. I answered the question that you asked. I absolutely did not address the "failing that" clause. I address the main drift of the question that you asked. Namely "Is there a native implementation of JSON in Windows that I can call from C?" It's not fair that you expected an answer to a question that you only asked 18 months after the original question! All you had to do was realise that you asked the wrong question, and then ask the right one.

Answer (score 2):

There is a long list of such things on the [JSON homepage](http://www.json.org/). Take your pick.

Comment: Ah so no native API then. This will have to do (-:

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something native now but that it's pretty new, maybe Windows 8/RT only? I don't have either OS at this point ...

Comment: Please don't change a two year old question to ask something completely different that makes an accepted answer look stupid. I reverted the question to the form that I answered two years ago. If you want to ask a different question, just ask a new question.